# Passing an array from Perl to PHP using JSON-RPC

Tags: php, arrays, json, perl, json-rpc

I am trying to pass an array from Perl to PHP using JSON-RPC. So here's the Perl routine which forms the arrays and returns it:

```
sub queueMemberList() : Public()
{       
        my @qNames;
        $connection = ConnectToMySql($dbName);
        $query = "select membername from queue_members";
        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
        print $statement->execute();
                while(@data = $statement->fetchrow())
                {       #$sendStr = $sendStr."+".$data[0];
                        push(@qNames, $data[0]);
                }
        return \@qNames;
}

sub ConnectToMySql 
{       my ($db) = @_;
        open(ACCESS_INFO, "<accessAdd") || die "Can't access login credentials";
                my $dbName = <ACCESS_INFO>;
                my $host = <ACCESS_INFO>;
                my $userid = <ACCESS_INFO>;
                my $passwd = <ACCESS_INFO>;
                my $connectionInfo="dbi:mysql:$db;$host";
        close(ACCESS_INFO);

        chomp ($dbName, $host, $userid, $passwd);
        my $db_connection = DBI->connect($connectionInfo,$userid,$passwd);
        return $db_connection;
}
```

As you can see, I've passed an array reference, like I normally would in Perl (and if a Perl program were accepting it, I would convert it back into an array). Now, this is the PHP I have which calls the routine above and attempts to display the array. Since I do not know how to convert it back, I've simple issued and `echo` statement.

```
<?php
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
        error_reporting(-1);

        require_once '/usr/src/jsonrpcphp/includes/jsonRPCClient.php';
        $myJSONconn2 = new jsonRPCClient('http://localhost:42337/jsonrpc/API/testArray');
        echo "Choose Member:<br>";
        try
        {       echo $myJSONconn2->queueMemberList();

        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                echo nl2br($e->getMessage()).'<br />'."\n";
        }
?>
```

The Current output simply shows `Array` on the browser and nothing else.

Could you please help me in converting it back into an array?

**EDIT:** As suggested by @grebneke, I replaced `echo` with `var_dump` which gives me the following output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "messi" [1]=> string(5) "lampard" }
```

And when I tried it using `print_r`, this is what I get:

```
Array ( [0] => messi [1] => rahul )
```

What does this mean in PHP?

Comment: Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to check the data in PHP, that will show you how to proceed.

Comment: @grebneke - Edited question with the output - What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your output of `var_dump`/`print_r`, `$myJSONconn2->queueMemberList()` returns  an ordinary `PHP array` where the first item is `"messi"` and the second is `"rehul"`:

```
$response = $myJSONconn2->queueMemberList();  // $response is now an array
print $response[0];                           // this will print: messi
```

or loop it:

```
foreach ($response as $data) {
    print $data;
}
```

I don't know if this is what you're expecting. But no need to "convert it back to an array" - it **is** an array already.

Comment: so did you mean that $response is an array so I could loop over it using `for` or `while` like I normally would for a PHP array?

Comment: Yes, it's a completely normal PHP array!

Comment: If you will be doing more PHP development, I recommend reading up on [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/var_dump) and [print_r()](http://www.php.net/var_dump). It is often very useful to dump an object or array to see exactly what data you're working with.